# Extraer links https o http BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

He estado intentando extraer links de pastebin con una página. Me da los links, sin embargo me da links no deseados.

Ejm: /api, /login...

Yo quiero solo los links `https y http` que son los de pastebin.

```
url = "https://psbdmp.ws"
params = {"string": "spotify"}
html = reqs.post(url, data=params).text
print(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links = link.get('href')
    print(links)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `soup.findAll` tambien acepta un parámetro `attrs` en el que se le puede
pasar un diccionario con los atributos de los nodo HTML que buscamos. A su vez cada
atributo puede ser una expresión regular, para filtrar solo los nodos que tengan ese
atributo y la cumplan. Así tenemos:

```
import re

pastebin_regex = re.compile(r"^https://pastebin.com/[\w]+$")

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={"href": pastebin_regex}):
   print(link["href"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Al traer todos los `Anchor` (`<a>`) , vas a traer desde la barra de navegación de la parte superior, hasta los que estan dentro de la tabla `<tbody>`.

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar algunas preguntas en tu código para no mostrarlas:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    try:
        if link.get('href').find('pastebin.com') != -1:
                print(link)
    except:
        pass
```

De esa manera estamos pidiendo que solo nos muestre los links que contienen "pastebin.com".

De todas formas, otra opción más sencilla, podría ser buscando los elementos que contiene la tabla `<tbody>`, o sea `<td>`, llegando al mismo resultado:

```
for i in soup.find_all('td'):
    if i.a != None:
        print("*"*100)
        print(i.a.text)
        print(i.a.get('href'))
```

Y de una manera más elegante:

```
[[i.a.get('href'),i.a.text] for i in soup.find_all('td') if i.a != None]
```